# Duplicate controls with same ID in a separate repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm just wondering whether I can use this method. I have set of controls in a repeater then use the same set in another repeater, calling the same function/method but passing different commandName or Argument. what problems will I have?

I'm using namingcontainer of course to do whatever I need with each controls.

I've searched and saw that this wont work with panels but I'm not sure about different repeaters.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like it is something really simple to test yourself.  I will add that controls inside a repeater I believe have the name of the container control (the ID of the repeater) as part of their final ID when they are rendered.  You can view this behavior by viewing the source of your web page when it is rendered in the browser.

Comment: Try to implement and post code if you face any problem with this.